# Input elements on android 4.x can not be styled when focused

Tags: android, css, cordova, mobile-webkit

**Update:**

There is a fix:

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

**Original question:**

I am trying to boil this down to a simple example:

I have a simple input element like this:

```
<input class="myclass" type="text"/>
```

the style looking like:

```
.myclass, .myclass:focus {
   background-color: black;
}
```

this works fine on android 2.x and 3.x (except some devices that are known not to respect css on focused input elements)

Since I updated a nexus S to 4.0.3 I can`t get the input field to accept any styles.

Some testing revealed the following:
The styles are actually applied, but for some reasons the browser renders a white rectangle over the input, rendering styles useless. Using Weinre i was able to move the "real" input element, so that I was able to display both.

Any suggestion on this are very much welcome.

Comment: I'm not familiar with webkit on Android, but perhaps setting `-webkit-appearance: none;` might prevent Webkit from tying to set its default focus styles.

Comment: already tried that, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Does it work if you tap twice?

Comment: Wow, where did you find the workaround? It works! Wooho!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is related to the Nexus S and its poor performance with ICS / Android 4. The roar of problems with Phonegap, jQuery mobile, Sencha and on is deafening. From the ignoring of Viewport meta tags to mal-positioned z-order, The Chromium Android browser is just a massive problem.

1. Have you tried turning off openGL?
2. Have you tried separating the pseudo selectors?

It seems that Androids WebView is continually getting worse... which is odd as it "should" be improving. I'm having a ton of trouble myself with scrolling and flickering. A lot of frameworks are actually considering bailing on Android.

A link that may interest you:
Problems with jQM and (mostly) Nexus S
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquerymobile-1-0-does-not-support-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hope this helps and you are not alone!

Comment: turning of openGL does not change anything, toying around with the selectors does not change anything..., thanks for your effort, I feared that this is just one more thing of that bad bad android browser. I'll leave the question open some more...

Answer (score 5):

This is likely related to these two issues:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24746
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24780

Comment: I've added comments to the 24746 thread about same issue. I suggest others star and comment on that thread to help gain traction. Thanks.